# Probability Problem - Check if I am right?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am currently working on a probability question and was wondering if I am doing it right.

(a) Suppose you flip 4 coins. Flips are independent, with the probability of
heads being 0.5 for each flip. Find the probability that at least two flips land on heads.

*My Answer*

1. Find the complement: P(0 or 1 flips land on heads out of the 4)
2. Use combinations: 0 heads = 4C0 = 1 | 1 head = 4C1 = 4. 4 + 1 = 5
3. There are 5/16 chances that we get 0 or 1 head in 4 flips
4. Switch back over: 1 - (5/16) = .6875 chance at least 2 of the 4 flips land heads

(b) Find the conditional probability that all four flips land heads given that at least $\color{red}{two}$ flips land heads.

*My Answer*

1. Create conditional: P(4 flips land heads) = P(A). P(at least 2 flips land heads) = P(B).
   We are looking for P(A | B)
2. P(A | B) = P(A intersection B) / P(B)
3. Plug in values: P(A intersection B) = P({H, H, H, H}) = (1/2)^4 = .0625. P(B) = .6875.
4. .0625 / .6875 = .090909 = 9.09% is the probability that if you land at least 2 heads, you will flip all heads.

Is this right?

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that relates closely to the content of your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your responses may be summarized as (a) 11/16, (b) 1/11, both of which are correct.

Comment: For b), you can think about it this way:  As you already figured out in a), out of the 16 possible outcomes, there are 5 cases where you do not get at least two heads, meaning that there are 11 cases where you do have at least two heads. Not, out of those 11, there is exactly one where you have all 4 heads. So: the probability is $\frac{1}{11}$.  I find that this kind of counting is often far more insightful than just plugging numbers into formulas.